# Math with very large numbers using strings

Tags: c#, string, math, numbers

I'm trying to use strings to do math with very large numbers using strings, and without external libraries.

I have tried looking online with no success, and I need functions for addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division (if possible, and limited to a specified number of decimal places.)

example: add 9,900,000,000
and                 100,000,020
should be 10,000,000,020.

EDIT: Im sorry I diddn't be specific enough, but I can only use Strings. no Long, bigInt, anything.
just the basic string and if nessecary, int32.

This is NOT a homework question!

Comment: Int64 will do that. You dont even need a 'big number'.

Comment: `and limited to a specified number of decimal places.` do you need support for decimals at all? Otherwise `long` and `BigInteger` are out.

Comment: Why are you rejecting BigInt? "Hi, I have a problem, and object X was designed to solve exactly this problem. How can I solve the problem without using X?"

Comment: @RaymondChen: It's probably a homework problem. lpquarx: Is it a homework problem? If so, explain what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. Can you solve the problem in strings to do, say, addition of two-digit numbers?

Comment: This is NOT a homework question.

Comment: The restrictions you specify are unusual in a real environment. Perhaps people would be more inclined to help if they understood *why* you can't use BigInteger in this context.

Answer (score 7):

Have you looked at [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET Framework 4, you can make use of the new `System.Numerics.BigInteger` class, which is an integer that can hold any whole number at all, until you run out of memory.

(The examples you provide, by the way, can be computed using `long` or `System.UInt64`.)

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert the value in bits first & then apply the operation which you wish. After operation, you should convert back the bits to the number.

Comment: Are you talking about converting to string of bits? Because "I can only use Strings. no Long, bigInt, anything. just the basic string and if nessecary, int32."